# ifstream::is_open returns true even if file is not existing at the location

Tags: c++

I have a function which basically opens the file from the location and parses the value available in the file into some structure used in some other places of source code.
Problem here is **even if the file is not available in the mentioned location, ifstream::isopen is returning true**.

Instead of using constructor i tried using ifstream::open to explicitly open the file but unfortunately it didn't work.

```
bool ClassName::loadRecordingConfiguration() 
{
     std::string filepathConfig = getDataFolder() + std::string("\\file.json");
     std::ifstream jsonFile(filepathConfig.c_str());
     if (jsonFile.is_open()) {
         //This part is executed when getDataFolder failed to return the folder path and file.json is not available
         //This part is also executed when getDataFolder returns correct folder path and file.json is available
     }
}

//Returns the folder path if SomeCondition is satisfied
std::string ClassName::getDataFolder() 
{
    if (SomeCondition) {
        return std::string(SomeFilePath);
    }
    return std::string("");
}
```

As the folder path is not correct, **i'm expecting it to work only when i have got file.json placed at soomeFilePath location**.

Comment: When `getDataFolder()` fails, does it return an empty sting like displayed? If so, have you checked that `./file.json` doesn't exist, where `.` denotes the working directory where you execute the program? Or does `file.json` not exist altogether --- but `is_open()` is still returning `true`? Also, filling in the placeholder names and showing more or less the current directory tree to get a minimal working example would help.

Comment: You say: "Instead of using constructor i used ifstream::open to explicitly open the file.".
But in your example you use constructor to open it actually. `std::ifstream jsonFile(filepathConfig.c_str());`

Comment: @anakhand yes when getDataFolder is failed it returns an empty string as displayed. I ensured that file.json doesn't exist anywhere in the working directory..

Comment: @Oliort I updated the comments again. Sorry for incorrect description

Comment: Any idea how ifstream looks to open file if the mentioned file is not available in the path??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `operator bool` (`if (jsonFile){ ... }`) or checking stream flags (badbit, failbit). Opening a file is very OS-specific operation and `ifstream::is_open()` checks only if it managed to create handle to file.

In any case it is better to check if it is present first with some OS API ([PathFileExistsA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfileexistsa) for Windows for example).

Comment: There is `ifstream::good()` that checks for all the error bits at once.

Comment: @oliort I found the problem. When getDataFolder() retutned NULL filepathConfig=\file.json.
With the help of GetFullPathName API i found the absolute path and the file was taken from the current directory which was in my case is U:\file.json.
I removed the file and it worked for me. Thanks for directing me in the right path.